# Project new objects from jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to project objects from a jQuery selection?  As a simplified example, let's say I want an array of objects, corresponding to my page's anchors; in each object, txt refers to the anchor's text, and val refers to the data-id attr therein.

```
var result = [];
$("a").each(function(i, o) {     
    result.push({ txt: $(o).text(), val: $(o).data("id") }); 
});
doSomething(result);
```

Is it possible to do something like a C# Select:

```
doSomething($("a").select(
    function(i, o) { return { txt: $(o).text(), val: $(o).data("id") }; 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method to project a set:

```
doSomething($("a").map(function(o, i) { 
    return { txt: $(o).text(), val: $(o).data("id") }; 
});
```

Remark: notice that the `index` and `element` parameters are inversed in the anonymous callback compared to the `.each` method. Don't ask why :-) If you don't care about the index you could simply omit them and do this:

```
doSomething($("a").map(function() { 
    return { txt: $(this).text(), val: $(this).data("id") }; 
});
```

Comment: **THAT'S** what I was trying to remember.  Thank you!

Comment: You'll probably want a `get` on the end of that, since `map` (inexplicably) returns a `jQuery` wrapper around the array rather than the actual array. (This is mentioned in the [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) documentation.)